# how do I use the same link to "re-hide" previously hidden text via Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The below code snippet shows the invite code when I click "Invite Code".  But how do I re-hide the invite code if the same link is clicked again?  And can it be done where it cycles back and forth with subsequent clicks?  I didn't write this code but merely modified it to my use. I am still very new to this type of thing.  Thanks!

```
<style>
    div.hide { display:none; }
    div.show { text-align:center; }
</style>



<script type='text/javascript'>
    function showText(show, hide) {
        document.getElementById(show).className = "show";
        document.getElementById(hide).className = "hide";
    }
</script>

<br>
<font color="red">-</font><a href="index.php">Home</a><font color="red"> / </font><a onclick="showText('text1')" href="javascript:void(0);">Invite Code</a>-</font>
<div id="text1" class="hide"><font color="red">abc123</font></div>
</center></h3>
```

Comment: do you not just use **document.getElementById("myDivsName").style.visibility = "hidden";**

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can also do an if statement on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use this function:

```js
function showText(id)
{
  var elem = document.getElementById(id);
  if(elem.style.display == 'none')
  {
   elem.style.display = 'inline';
  }
  else
  {
   elem.style.display = 'none';
  }
}
```

```html
<a onClick="showText('text1');" href="#">Show or Hide</a><br/>
<div style="height: 30px;"><div id="text1" style="display: none;">Text to hide or show... WTF?!</div></div>
<div>This text should not move.</div>
```

**PS: This also works for 2 Elements...**

Greetings

Comment: `elem.style.display = (elem.style.display == 'none')?'inline':'none';`.. just to make it one line.

Comment: Also good but to make the code more comprehensible it's sometimes better to write more lines...

Comment: One thing I noticed, if I use your solution on a page other than index, when I click "get code" it works, but returns to index.  Any way to remove the need for the anchor link and just make it styled text but still with the onclick?

Comment: Just change the # to `javascript:void(0)`  Greetings

Comment: @Bernd One more thing, I have it so the hidden "invite code" appears directly below the link when revealed. But it pushes all the content below it down one line.  How can I prevent this?  I know it's just cosmetic but it's bugging me. :D

Comment: @Bernd any idea how to make "shown" links stay open even if I refresh the page and/or until I "hide" the link? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

save the state with a boolean

```
var hided = true;
function showText(show,hide){
    if (hided){
        document.getElementById(show).className = "show";
        document.getElementById(hide).className = "hide";
    }
    else{
        document.getElementById(show).className = "hide";
        document.getElementById(hide).className = "show";
    }
    hided = !hided;
}
```

fiddle with this code and some of your html : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0hccwfws/3/), 
isn't it the expected behavior ?

Comment: ..and also in CSS, the `div.show` should have `display: block` or other value (_except `none`_) to make the element visible again.

Comment: no, because the .className = "show" is removing the "hide" class

Comment: This doesn't seem to work and produces the same effect as the original code. I do see what you are trying to do here and it makes sense.  Is there an error in your code perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

I really don't see the use for the show class. You could just toggle the hide class on the elements that you want to toggle.
Assume you dont need the show class, then use the classList.toggle function like this

```js
function toggle(target){
  document.getElementById(target).classList.toggle('hide');
}
```

```css
.hide{ display:none }
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle('test')">Show / Hide</button>
<div id="test" class="hide">Hello world!</div>
```

Comment: I like the button idea, but I'd like it plain text for now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<div ID="content" style="display:block;">This is content.</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleContent() {
  // Get the DOM reference
  var contentId = document.getElementById("content");
  // Toggle 
  contentId.style.display == "block" ? contentId.style.display = "none" : 
contentId.style.display = "block"; 
}
</script>

<button onclick="toggleContent()">Toggle</button>

</html>
```

//Code is pretty self explanatory.